# Quicksort a list of list by column

Tags: python, list, quicksort

i would like to quicksort a list of list which i generatet from a csv via pandas.
I want to sort it by a specific column e.g. number oder height.

The Data looks like this:

| Number | Name | Height | Width | Weigth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hatity | 66.23 | 57.28 | 124.87 |
| 2 | Bamity | 22.56 | 843.7 | 123.67 |
| 3 | Asoka | 45.66 | 234.3 | 523.29 |

I was already able to sort it by the second column with this code:

```
def quickSort(list):
  if not list:
      return list
  pivot = list[0]
  lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if x[1] < pivot[1]])
  greater = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if x[1] >= pivot[1]])
  return lesser + [pivot] + greater
print(quickSort(product_list))
```

This is working fine for sorting by name. But i dont know what to change to sort by any other column.
It would be great if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
product_list = [[1,10],[3,8],[2,9]]

def quickSort(list, compare_fn):
  if not list:
      return list
  pivot = list[0]
  lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if compare_fn(x, pivot)], compare_fn)
  greater = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if not compare_fn(x, pivot)], compare_fn)
  return lesser + [pivot] + greater
print(quickSort(product_list, lambda x,y: x[0] < y[0]))
```