# How does my Quick Sort algorithm work exactly?

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I know how the Quick Sort algorithm works in theroy:

Concept of Divide and Conquer.
Dividing the list into three main parts:

Elements less than the Pivot element,

Pivot element(Central element),

Elements greater than the pivot element

Repeat this until everything is sorted and put it back together.

I have implemented a quick sort algorithm in my python code, and it works fine.
But I do not understand exactly how it works:

```
def quickSort(list, compare_fn):

if not list:
    return list
pivot = list[0]
lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if compare_fn(x, pivot)], compare_fn)
greater = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if not compare_fn(x, pivot)], compare_fn)
return lesser + [pivot] + greater

product_list = quickSort(product_list, lambda x,y: x[z] < y[z])
```

"z" is the variable by which column the list should be sorted.

I would be very happy if someone could explain to me exactly how the function works.
I am also not sure what lambda does in this context

I would really appreciate help

Comment: Did you write the function yourself? If not, it might help to try and replicate the output using your own script and the steps you have listed.

Comment: You already asked about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181172

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quicksort a list of list by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181172/quicksort-a-list-of-list-by-column)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple really... let's start with the invocation:

`product_list = quickSort(product_list, lambda x,y: x[z] < y[z])`

The `lambda` defines an anonymous function (a "lambda") that takes two values, x and y, and checks to see if `x[z]` is less than `y[z]`. In your quicksort, this is the `compare_fn` - a function that takes two values and returns `True` if the first value is less than the second and `False` otherwise.

Why bother? Well... doing it this way means `quicksort` can be written without knowing *how* you decide what "less" means in your context. But also, what if the elements are objects? Easy: Just pass in a lambda that compares the fields.

Next: The quicksort itself.

- `pivot` - your code just takes the first element of the list. It doesn't really matter *which* element you use to pivot on (*unless* you have more knowledge of the list, but you don't in the general case)
- inside the two (recursive) calls to `quickSort`, you have `[x for x in list[1:] if compare_fn(x, pivot)]` (and the opposite for `greater`).

this `[x for x in list[1:] ...]` construct is a *list comprehension*. `list[1:]` is a copy of your list, except the first element (the pivot). For `lesser` we only use the elements that are less than pivot, for `greater` only those that are not less than pivot.

This algorithm employs something called *recursion*. Basically, `quickSort` uses `quickSort` to calculate it's result. Look it up, other's can explain this much better than I.

In the end, you just append all the lists (`lesser`, a list with just the `pivot`, and `greater`) and return that.